# Why DATEADD is not getting data from past month?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have this query if I'm correct it should get the data from the past month.

```
   select * from INTRANET.DBO.CSEReduxResponses where status=1 and execoffice_status=0 
   AND MONTH([approveddate])= DATEADD(MONTH,-1,GETDATE())
```

But it's not returning anything.
I know by looking at the data that a row does exist:
[image]

Why is the select statement not returning anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to compare the month and year component on both dates. The correct query is as follows:

```
select * from INTRANET.DBO.CSEReduxResponses where status=1 and execoffice_status=0 
AND MONTH([approveddate])= MONTH(DATEADD(MONTH,-1,GETDATE()))
AND YEAR([approveddate])= YEAR(DATEADD(MONTH,-1,GETDATE()))
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want everything from the previous month, you have to do something like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM INTRANET.DBO.CSEReduxResponses 
WHERE status=1 
  AND execoffice_status=0 
  AND [approveddate] between 
     DATEADD(DAY, (DATEPART(DAY, getdate())*-1)+1,DATEADD(MONTH,-1,GETDATE())) --gets the first day of the previous month
       AND 
     DATEADD(DAY, (DATEPART(DAY, getdate())*-1), GETDATE()) --gets the last day of the previous  month
```